# CKEditor multiple user access

Tags: ckeditor

Does CKEditor solve the problems of multiple users accessing and editing the same file? If so, are there any configuration options available? If not, what are the possibilities of implementing custom multi-user behaviour? Or, are there any alternative editors with similar features and multi-user support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor is only "a text editor", not a CMS. It doesn't know if the content is a file, a DB record, that's up to you to create the proper framework around it or to use an existing one.